# How to create html node from html string?

Tags: c#, html

Suppose I have a html string and I have to create it into html node. How could I do it? Please give an example. Let I have

```c#
 var table1 = @"<table> 
 <tr> <th>DEPART</th> <th>ARRIVE</th> <th>PASSENGER</th> </tr>
 <tr> <td>Hyderabad</td> <td>Delhi</td> <td>William</td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>chennai</td> <td>london</td> <td>James</td> </tr>
 </table>";
```

What would be the output?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery / javascript you can use Append

http://api.jquery.com/append/